# Установка кодировки при подключении к MySQL через JDBC

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Как при подключении через JDBC к MySQL сообщить кодировку передаваемых данных.
Подключение происходит на серевере Tomcat через JNDI.
Проблема с кодировкой есть только когда добавляются данные, содержащие кирилицу через программу, использующую БД. Если запустить `.sql` скрипт, то проблем нету.

Comment: а почему вам не создать базу данных в Mysql с нужной уже вам кодировкой? Как то так CREATE DATABASE dbname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

Comment: ну или в пуле соединений поиграться параметром characterEncoding

Comment: @plesser, БД создавалась так `CREATE DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`. В файле с параметрами подключения прописывание `characterEncoding` не помогает.

Comment: COLLATE utf8_bin - вот это есть?

Comment: @plesser, нету.

Comment: попробуйте ее. я сам в свое время с mysql настрадался из за этой проблемы

Comment: @plesser, не помогло и хотелось бы знать, что значит эта стпрочка. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи кодировки при подключении к БД необходимо в файле `context.xml`  добавить к `url` подключения параметр, в котором указан тип кодировки
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?characterEncoding=utf8`.
Так же можно установить передаваемые параметры используя свойство `connectionProperties="characterEncoding=utf8;"`